# Host Google-Account-Protected Webpage

Tags: authorization, google-cloud-storage

Is it somehow possible to host a static webpage on google cloud storage which is protected by the "normal" google login mechanism. Basically that users need to enter their google username and password before seeing the webpage?
I already know that it is possible to set permissions by giving users email adresses. But I don't think my use case is supported. Although it would be very convenient.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking to open your page to all Google Account holders, you can use the `AllAuthenticatedUsers` scope in your ACL for the webpage object.

Then anyone logged into Google will be able to access the page via http://storage.cloud.google.com/yourbucket/yourwebpage.html.  Note that the user will be redirected to a `commondatastorage.googleapis.com` location that serves the page, so relative links from `yourwebpage.html` would not work.

If you are looking to restrict the webpage to a specific Google group of account holders (as opposed to **all** Google account holders), you can grant access to a `Group` instead of `AllAuthenticatedUsers`.

For details on how to set an `AllAuthenticatedUsers` or a `Group` access control, see the [Access Control Documentation](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol).

Comment: Hot being able to have relative links is exactely my problem. With this restriction, it's not possible to host google-account-protected webpages ...